# javascript: Prevent representing added Array's attributes as elements (in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome

I am using this snippet to extend Array's functionality with getUnique function:

```
Array.prototype.getUnique = function() {
   var u = {}, a = [];
   for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i) {
      if (u.hasOwnProperty(this[i])) {
         continue;
      }
      a.push(this[i]);
      u[this[i]] = 1;
   }
   return a;
};
```

The slight drawback is that the attribute getUnique is printed together with array elements if I console.log an array:

```
["126", "125", getUnique: function]
```

It is slightly disturbing even if I know that getUnique is not considered as an array element. This happens in Chrome. Not in Firefox as far as I know. Is there a way to prevent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Object.defineProperty` and `enumerable`:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'getUnique',
{ enumerable: false
, configurable: true
, writable: true
, value: function ()
   {  var u = {};
      var a = [];
      for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i)
      {  if (u.hasOwnProperty(this[i])) continue;
         a.push(this[i]);
         u[this[i]] = 1;
      }
      return a;
   }
});
```

By default, a property is enumerable (even if it's not a direct property of an instance), which means that it is visible through any for-in loop (or `Object.keys`) of the array. Chrome does something similar to a for-in loop on an array, which is why it is represented as it is.

Note that this function only works in (relatively) modernish browsers which support ES5, which means that IE < 9, some older Android browsers and other mobile devices may not be able to use this code. This is one of the reasons why some people recommend against extending the prototypes of native constructors, as this issue can break code that isn't well constructed against these issues. What people who believe this usually recommend is to not place the function on the prototype:

```
function getUnique(arr)
{  var u = {};
   var a = [];
   for (var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; ++i)
   {  if (u.hasOwnProperty(arr[i])) continue;
      a.push(arr[i]);
      u[arr[i]] = 1;
   }
   return a;
}
```

I'd also like to point out that only one object will be ever printed by the `getUnique` function, as it is technically incorrect in its implementation. While rather similar, **objects are not dictionaries** and can only have string keys, which means that any object (no matter the contents) will have a string value of `'[object Object]'`, which means that when your function encounters another object (even if it has different values), it will not be added to the returned array. While inefficient, the only way I can think of is to iterate through the array each time:

```
function getUnique(arg)
{  'use strict';
   var O = Object(arg);
   var len = O.length >>> 0;
   var A = [];
   var indexOf = function (arg, searchElement)
   {  for (var i = 0, l = arg.length; i < l; ++i) if (arg[i] === searchElement) return i;
      return -1;
   };
   for (var k = 0; k < len; ++k)
   {  var elementK = O[k];
      var kPresent = k in O;
      if (!kPresent || indexOf(A, elementK) !== -1) continue;
      A[A.length - 1] = elementK;
   }
   return array;
}
```

Comment: Thx, I need IE8 support so I'll probably use the method in question (which should work everywhere, right?). But it is good to know the background.

Comment: Or does the method in question have the same problems with support as your suggestion? (I didn't notice any problems with the method in question under IE8)

Comment: @clime: try defining your function as in your question, creating an array, and looping through it using a for-in loop. Log what `i` is every time, and see if it's there or not.

Comment: With your method the getUnique function is not printed as an array element anymore (in Chrome). But I am asking about support of these two solutions (mine original, and yours). Are these two solutions supported equally in browsers or not? And by support I mean that it doesn't break site.

Comment: @clime: by work you mean produce the "right" results, my code will not work in IE8 as `Object.defineProperty` is not supported for non-DOM elements -- yours will. However, it will introduce the problem with for-in loops that I have discussed and that you have found out yourself.

Comment: @clime: it's dawned on me that your function is technically incorrect, see my edit.